# Logging and debug messages

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have my debug messages evaluate expensive string operations when printing messages like this:

`Log.Debug("here it is" + obj.ExpensiveToString())`

Now even if the log level isn't set to `Debug`, it still evaluates the expensive string operation.

So without having to do this:

`if(debugMode) Log.Debug("here it is" + obj.ExpensiveToString())`

or having lots of complex `Log.Debug()` methods, how can I get around this?

Comment: If you are using log4net it is better to add that tag to your question. An expert will notice it faster.

Comment: i think it will always evaluate that expression irrespective of the configuration because obj.ExpensiveToString() goes as a argument to the function and it must be evaluated in order to call the function. they can only check the configuration when it goes inside the function call

Comment: @Steve I am not using log4net

Comment: @sumeetkumar - That's not true.  If `debugMode` is false, it won't even try to evaluate the `Log.Debug()` function.

Comment: you may be write if the compiler knows about the that call e.g. Trace and Debug.WriteLine. but in any other case it will treat it as a general method and execute it unless you have predefined directives set as suggested answer.

Answer (score 3):

use a compiler directive

```
#if DEBUG
  Log.Debug("Here it is: "+obj.ExpensiveToString());
#endif
```

since these directives increase code verbosity use them for the expensive parts.

Another alternative is to modify or supplement your log system to accept a `Func<string>`

```
public void LogDebug(Func<string> evalMe){

#if DEBUG
    if (evalMe!=null)
      Log.Debug(evalMe);
#endif

}
```

and then call it like this:

```
LogDebug(()=>"Here it is: "+obj.ExpensiveToString());
```

Comment: Thats an interesting solution, but surely the `Fun<string>` adds overhead of its own?

Comment: the Func<> will only be carried as a "pointer" to code that's compiled runtime, it won't be evaluated in DEBUG mode, so the overhead is very minimal and on par with passing parameters of any other kind. For example adding `if (debugMode)` is probably a tiny bit slower

Comment: Don't like the compiler directive idea. This means you can't change the logging level just by editing a config file, but instead have to ship a new debug build.

Comment: with the function parameter you could replace the compiler directive with an `if (debugMode)` check.